# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work in SKView

Tags: sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I have in my view controller this code running scene :

```
SKView * _skView;
ClassicGameScene* _scene;


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    if (!_skView) {
        _skView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        ClassicGameScene *scene =[[ClassicGameScene alloc] initWithSize:_skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        [_skView presentScene:scene];
        [self.view addSubview:_skView];
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        _scene = scene;
    };
}
```

And in my scene I have this one :

```
- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        [self createSceneContents];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) createSceneContents
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [self addBackground];
    [self addLabels];
    [self preparePlocha];
}
```

But when I tap on scene, my gesture recognizer doesn't
work (tap procedure is not fired - tested through breakpoint). Can someone help me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: How did you implement the tap: method?

Comment: -(void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
       NSLog(@"Tapped");
    }

Comment: Why do you manually create the SKView and add it as subview of the view controller's view? What's the actual view? You may want to try [_skView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap].

Comment: self.view is nil in initWithSize. You should call createSceneContents from didMoveToView.